# Netlogo: resetting event every tick, but tick counter goes on

Tags: netlogo

Trying to let a flood appear with every tick and make it disappear after every tick as well. Meanwhile, the tick counter should go on.
The flood appears this way:

```
to water_rise
 ask patches [  ; saturates cell
  if is-DEM < 800[
      set cell-storage cell-storage + fill-rate
    ]
  ]

  ask patches [
    if any? neighbors4 with [ any? turtles-here ] [
      set cell-storage cell-storage + fill-rate
    ]
  ]
  ask patches [
    if cell-storage > 0 [
      if cell-storage > 5 [
        set cell-storage 5
        if not any? turtles-here [
          sprout 1 [
            set color blue
            set size 10
            set shape "circle"
          ]
        ]
      ]
      set pcolor cell-storage + 82
    ]
  ]
end
```

Currently trying to figure out how to let the flood disappear after/or within this the tick, so that it can reoccur in the next one. I´m not aiming to reset the tick counter, it should reach 200.
Tried resetting the ticks, but only to manage resetting everything.

Any ideas ?
Thank you very much in adavance

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `display` primitive to update the view without waiting for the tick counter to advance.

I am not familiar with your whole model but here's a conceptual example that may help:

```
to water_rise
  ...
end
    
to go
  repeat 100 [
    water-rise
      display
    ]
  tick
end
```

This code would execute your water-rise procedure 100 times, update the view with new patch colors after each execution, and only increase the tick counter by 1 after the `repeat` loop is done.

Here is the link to NetLogo Dictionary entry about the `display` primitive:
http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#display

Note: due to its design, NetLogoWeb does not support the `display` primitive. So, you need to use the desktop version.